# Google Sheets Sort rows by highly active non blank first?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large sheet where participant data are entered in either positive or negative values. If they did not participate the cell is blank.

```
         D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6
Player1  20  -5   3  50     -10
Player2      10   8      -8 
Player3      -9  98  46  -89 
Player4  10      25
```

I would like to sort by most active players to least, how to achieve that?
As of now I'm summing the data and sorting high to low now but it is evidently inaccurate to know the "highly active"

Comment: Please provide more insight on what is D1, D2 , D3 etc. and what is definition of active player.

Comment: D1, D2, D3 are dates. Active player is if data is present in most cells of the row and not blank. In above example player1, player 3, player2,player4 is the order of sorting, expected "highly active" output.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can introduce a new column (say Nonparticipation) in the start, I mean immediately after Player name column and use COUNTBLANK function to check how many blank cells are there in a row, and then sort that column Nonparticipation from lowest to highest, so lowest value of Nonparticipation mean highest active player.